# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null (i don't want to use getElementsByClassName)

Tags: javascript, queryselector

I'm learning javascript, I tried to make a script to trigger a popup, but it doesn't work. Any ideas? 
Thanks for you help.

```
const popupExit = document.querySelector(".popup");

addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
    popupExit.querySelector(".popup").style.visibilty = "visible";
});
```

Comment: Adding `addEventListener` to which element?

Comment: It would be `window` I guess if no element

Comment: The whole document. Is it necessary to specify this when it is about the whole document?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and add relevant HTML, JavaScript and CSS

Comment: I would not expect you to be able to mouseout the document

Comment: Also you already have  popupExit - unless you have something inside it with class popup, you likely meant `popupExit.style.visibilty` and this is assuming your `const popupExit = document.querySelector(".popup");` is executed AFTER the popup has rendered on the page

Comment: Voting to close since the issue is _caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers_

Comment: `.popup` probably doen't exist at the time of executing the first line, so `popupExit` becomes `null`.

Comment: That, and there is likely nothing with class popup inside the popup @FZs see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60322618/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-queryselector-of-null-i-dont-want-t#comment106705823_60322618)

Comment: at first i tried that code but it doesn't work either.

const popupExit = document.querySelector(".popup");

addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
 popupExit.style.visibilty = "visible";
});

Comment: @FZs You're right, the js script was running before the .popup. (Noob Error)